# Assets broke the category image field

Tags: assets, image, categories

I'm using Assets in a MSM setup. But it seems that it broke the category image functionality. Is there a work-around or a fix for that?

Thanks,
Diederik.

Comment: Diederik - broke it how? Assets doesn't hook into that page right now, so it should not have had any impact on that page. Can you let me know your EE and Assets versions, and any errors you're seeing? Screenshots would help as well. If this is a problem with front-end templates, please include your template code. Thank you!

Comment: I'm using Assets 2.1.1, EE 2.6 and the latest version of MSM (don't know the number).

Comment: Actually, it's the javascript that stopped working. So it could be anything. I'll look into it with some developer tools!

Comment: Are you receiving a JS error, Diederik? Happy to help if I can!

Comment: Shamefully, it seems to be a JS error caused by a custom add-on I wrote. Forgot to check is an element was present before adding some functionality to it.

Comment: Glad you figured it out, Diederik!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to some JS errors in another custom made Accessory, the category image functionality was broken. This had nothing to do with Assets. Just wanted to put this straight.